# How to have resolvconf -u not put 127.0.01 in resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, debian, bind

I have an Ubuntu server running Bind9, which does not do recursion. I also don't want to use it for any kind of local DNS, because it may not reflect what the outside world sees (getting stale records, for instance). Therefore, the server itself should always use external DNS servers.

However, `resolvconf -u` seems to always put `127.0.0.1` in there, and I can't seem to turn it off.

`127.0.0.1` doesn't occur in any of the files in `/etc/resolvconf`.

Can that be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Because `/etc/default/bind9` had this in it:

```
RESOLVCONF=yes
```

A file `lo.named` was created in `/run/resolvconf/interface` with this in it:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

That was then added to `/etc/resolv.conf` by `resolvconf -u`

That begs the question, why would someone want to use their own server as authoritative nameserver? When a domain has a nameserver change, you will never get up-to-date information anymore.